# Couchbase or Riak as a data storage for search engine

Tags: indexing, couchdb, search-engine, riak, couchbase

I want to implement text search engine. Particular the document to index will be list of terms with weight.
The query is a simple list of terms.
The output of a search should be a sorted list by relevance match (against terms and their weights)
**The data I need to store is big! It won't fit in single node. So the final storage must be easy to distribute.**

Which database storage would you recommend?
After some analysis i would like to choose between Couchbase and Riak.

[edit]
**What do you think about simply relational databases?** They already have some nice mechanism for distribution (eg: Postgres 9 has build in)
[/edit]

Riak has buildin search functionality, but as far as I know i don't want to use it, because i need to have index to get response (instead to compute it for every query).

On the other hand Couchbase 2 "*adds secondary indexes for JSON documents. Indexes are created via Views which can then be queried. Indexing is evenly distributed.*" 
That sounds as a great benefit for Couchbase

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172496)

Comment: So where should i look for advice if I'm not expertized with couchbase or riak?

Comment: For text search consider Solr (mature but difficult to shard) or Elastic Search (designed to auto-shard). Then there is Lucene(like) integration in CouchDB, Riak or other NoSQL DBs for text search. Special: Sphinx full text storage for MySQL or other text search-RDBMS integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [Riak Search](http://wiki.basho.com/Riak-Search.html) for full-text search, it's quite powerful and borrowed most of advantages from [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), while still being transparently fault-tolerant, replicated and scalable. If your data does not fit on a single node it's probably the most balanced opensource solution.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, as in the question, I'm considering Riak. I'm looking for some recommendations or opinions from peoples how used it.

Comment: You can find many people who used Riak for very different purposes at Riak's mailing list: http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com

Answer (score 2):

To answer the general underlying question of "Can/Should I use a database for storage for my indexed documents?"

Yes.

This is a fairly common pattern.  Several organizations (names withheld to protect the innocent) use Solr as an index and relevance engine, returning only primary keys from searches, then turning around and retrieving actual documents from a DB store.

There are challenges with this approach however; primarily in keeping the two systems (solr and db) in sync.  Couchbase uses its Cross Data Center Replication technology for keeping ElasticSearch instances in sync; Riak 2 just released and effectively automatically creates a Solr index for each shard of the database.  Either works well, depending on your usecase. Additionally you can obviously do your own synchronization using queues, etc.

More details for the two DBs at

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/search/

Answer (score 1):

I used ElasticSearch and CouchDB and it works pretty well.

Comment: Just added missing requirement: storage must be easy to distribute, since the data size could go out of single node. Is ElasticSearch works well with data distribution?

Comment: Yes http://www.elasticsearch.org/ I don't know your exact specs but it sounds pretty damn close.  For more info check (us) out on Freenode (IRC) #elasticsearch